Error Index 2 is out of bounds (must be less than 2) error when delete row for Realm / SwiftUI
I faced this problem. When deleting a note in the List, I get an application crash and an Index 2 is out of bounds (must be less than 2) error. I tried to add 3 notes and when I deleted them, the application crashed when I deleted the first and second notes
How to solve this problem?
My viewmodel:
class NoteViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @ObservedResults(Note.self) var notes
    @Published var newNoteText: String = ""

    func addNote() {
      let realm = try! Realm()
      try! realm.write {
        let note = Note()
        note.id = getNextNoteId()
        note.title = newNoteText
        note.isCompleted = false
        realm.add(note)
        newNoteText = ""

      }
    }
    
    func deleteNote(atIndex index: Int) {
      guard notes.indices.contains(index) else { return }
      let noteToDeleteId = notes[index].id

      do {
        let realm = try Realm()
        try realm.write {
          if let noteToDelete = realm.objects(Note.self).filter("id == \(noteToDeleteId)").first {
            realm.delete(noteToDelete)
          }
        }
      } catch {
        print("Error deleting note: \(error.localizedDescription)")
      }
    }






     func markNoteAsCompleted(id: Int) {
        let realm = try! Realm()
        try! realm.write {
          guard let note = realm.objects(Note.self).filter("id == \(id)").first else { return }
          note.isCompleted = !note.isCompleted
        }
        objectWillChange.send()
      }
    }
  private func getNextNoteId() -> Int {
    let realm = try! Realm()
    return (realm.objects(Note.self).max(ofProperty: "id") ?? 0) + 1
  }

Here is the view in which I delete notes
struct NoteView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel = NoteViewModel()
//
.....
//


                        List {
                            ForEach(viewModel.notes) { note in
                                HStack {
                                    Toggle(isOn: Binding(
                                        get: { note.isCompleted },
                                        set: { newValue in
                                            viewModel.markNoteAsCompleted(id: note.id)
                                        }
                                    ), label: {
                                        Text(note.title)
                                            .strikethrough(note.isCompleted)
                                            .foregroundStyle(note.isCompleted ? Color("grey") : Color("white"))
                                        
                                        
                                        
                                    })
                                    
                                    .toggleStyle(iOSCheckboxToggleStyle())
                                    
                                    
                                }
                                .padding(10)
                                .listRowBackground(Color("backgroundLightSecond"))
                                
                            }
                            .onDelete(perform: { indexSet in
                              guard let index = indexSet.first else { return }
                              viewModel.deleteNote(atIndex: index)
                            })
                            .listRowSeparator(.hidden)
                            
                            
                        }
}

i tried many options but my app crashes

Not sure whether it's the only issue, but you should never use @ObservedObject where you own the object -- it should be @StateObject

@jnpdx thank you. I changed it, but the problem remained

I don't know swift, but this is a common problem in all languages. In your delete code you are somehow using the wrong value to refer to the item to be deleted. If you are deleting them in a loop from item 1 (which is index 0) then you can hit a problem after the first item is deleted. Try a reverse loop so delete index 2, then 1, then 0.

I might be wrong but I don’t ObservedResults isnt designed to work outside of a View. It is likely not observing, check documentation.

I may know the cause but the question really needs more information and some troubleshooting. Why is NoteViewModel an observable object? Aren't you wanting to observe the Realm objects for changes? That will refresh the view automatically. Also, Did you do some basic troubleshooting by adding a breakpoint and stepping through the code line by line, inspecting the vars and code execution until you spot something unexpected? If so, what line is not correct?
